# How can you unit test lib/src files in Dart?

Tags: unit-testing, dart

My Dart package is currently laid out in the following manner:

```
lib/
  mypackage.dart
  src/
    mypackage_util.dart
test/
  mypackage_test.dart
```

Inside `mypackage.dart`, I'm using the `part`, `part of` import strategy to use
`mypackage_util.dart` in `mypackage.dart`, [as recommended by the Pub Layout
conventions](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout.html).

On the test side, I took inspiration from [Seth Ladd's example of using
unittest](http://blog.sethladd.com/2013/01/holy-cow-dart-unit-tests-are-easy.html),
which shows him creating a new library for his tests, which makes sense to me.

Unfortunately, this leads to the inability to import `mypackage_util.dart` into
`mypackage_test.dart`, which means I can't test classes or functions from
`mypackage_util.dart`, or anything in `src/`.

The solutions I'm imagining are;

1. Make `mypackage_test.dart` a part of the main library, but this seems to make
   it impossible to just run the test code stand-alone.
2. Take `mypackage_util.dart` out of `src/`, but this seems to imply that you
   can never unit test `src/` code in packages, which seems silly and exposes
   code I don't want to.

Should I take one of the above approaches, or am I missing something?

---

**Update:**

The above situation was due to a library import conflict (see [Chapter 2. Dart Tour's Libraries and Visibility section](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#libraries) for solutions to library conflicts). [See comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25220292/3925304).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `lib/mypackage.dart` declares the library and includes `lib/src/mypackage_util.dart` using `part/part of` you just need to include `lib/mypackage.dart` in your test - or is your problem that you want to test private classes/functions contained in `lib/src/mypackage_util.dart`?

Comment: Unfortunately including `lib/mypackage.dart` does not expose classes in `lib/src/mypackage_util.dart` to the tester. I receive **type 'Blah' is not loaded** errors. I do not believe that things in `lib/src/mypackage_util.dart` are "private" other than the fact that they are not importable directly.

Comment: It doesn't matter if code (classes functions) are in the main library file or in the part. In Dart identifiers are private when they start with an underscore. If this doesn't work there is something wrong in your code/setup. Can you add the content of the files (mypackage.dart, mypackage_util.dart, mypackage_test.dart) a minimal example that allows to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Your suggestion to build the simple example showed me that you're right. My tester should have access to things inside `lib/src`, so it's something else wrong with my code structure or otherwise. Thanks!